# Does using Microsoft Outlook Junk E-mail filtering mean that Email contents or attributes are sent to Microsoft?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

I could not find details about how this feature works. I assume, that incoming email is sent at least partially to a service from Microsoft, thus affecting the users privacy.

Does anyone know if this is the case?

**edit**
@LPChip shared his information which was marked as answer. If anyone knows a safe written source that describes the privacy issues of the MS Junk options feature please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Outlook junk email filtering will not send email to microsoft for analysis.

There are a few things that make junkmail work in outlook.

**1. Classification by the spamfilter**
It is possible that the spamfilter classifies your email as spam. If so, it can block the mail, or it can flag the mail as spam, but still allow you to receive it. If the latter is true, outlook can then know before anything that it is spam, and thus move it to the junk mail.

**2. Identifying spam by typical spamming behavior**
A spam mail can be in many forms. It is possible that the layout of the email is close enough to that of what spammers usually use, like only an image, no text, certain words, etc... Simple spamfilters also classify spam based on these and give a score to the email. The more these actions are used, the higher the score. If a treshold is reached, it is considered spam.

There are more ways, but I don't know for sure if outlook also uses these, such as a blacklist for sender adresses or urls.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds good, but do you have a source from Microsoft for this? Or do you just assume that?

Comment: I did some research into this a while ago, and somewhere along the lines in one of the many talks I had with a microsoft representative this was discussed. Its one of the advantages when you work for a company that is a Microsoft Partner. :)

Comment: Which is more than Microsoft has to say about it... https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-the-Junk-Email-Filter-5ae3ea8e-cf41-4fa0-b02a-3b96e21de089